# Pythonic way to a double comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have to get a list of handles and labels from a figure, except in the cases where the label is "True" or "False". The following code accomplishes this:

```
# h, l = [a for a in ax.get_legend_handles_labels()] #redundant
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [a for a, b in zip(h, l) if (b != 'True' and b != 'False')]
labels = [b for a, b in zip(h, l) if (b != 'True' and b != 'False')]
```

Nevertheless, this seems completely "not-pythonic". Is there a more elegant way to solve this?
I tried the following 2-liner but I got a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` on line 2:

```
h, l = [a for a in ax.get_legend_handles_labels()]
handles, labels = [(a,b) for a, b in zip(h, l) if (b != 'True' and b != 'False')]
```

I'd expect Python to have a one-line solution...is there any?

For reproducibility:

```
(h,l)=(['handle1','handle2', 'handle3'],['label1','True', 'False'])
handles = [a for a, b in zip(h, l) if (b != 'True' and b != 'False')]
labels = [b for a, b in zip(h, l) if (b != 'True' and b != 'False')]
```

The intended output for this reproducible example is

```
handles=['handle1'] 
labels=['label1']
```

Comment: In the second version, you're creating a list of tuple, not a tuple of lists, hence the unpack error: handles would be the first (a,b) tuple, labels the second one, but there are more than 2 so it crashes. I don't have any idea on how to generate that tuple of list in the way you are trying to do it, maybe someone else will.

Comment: Also, your first line is redundant, since `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` already returns `(handles, label)`. You're basically doing `h, l = [a for a in (h, l)]`. Just do `h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` (source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip again:

```py
h, l = [a for a in ax.get_legend_handles_labels()]
filtered_hl = [(a,b) for a, b in zip(h, l) if (b != 'True' and b != 'False')]
handles, labels = map(list, zip(*filtered_hl))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique called "unzipping" an iterator (see fourth line in my code example), which is kind of a reshape of nested elements. It's a little bit like numpy's [swapaxes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) if you are familiar with it. Combining python's iterators `zip` and `filter` you can achieve the desired behaviour in the following way:

```
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
zipped = zip(h, l)
filtered = filter(lambda t: t[1] != 'True' and t[1] != 'False', zipped)
handles, labels = zip(*filtered)
```